# istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer showing “Pending” in AWS EC2 instances k8s

Tags: kubernetes, istio-gateway

Hi there folks need some help on this, I have a k8s on top of EC2 instances then I deploy istio, but it seems like I'm not getting Load Balancer for the istio-ingressgateway so I verify my app is ok since I do portforward and seems ok but I don't know is there is something missing in order to get istio up and running on this setup?? I check a thread about annotations but is not super clear to me if just by adding this to my svc will do the job and if every time I create a cluster I will need to do the annotations?

thanks for any advise :)

[image: issue and description of my svc]

Comment: How did you setup your Kubernetes cluster? Amazon EKS, kOps or maybe some bare-metal solution like `kubeadm`?

Comment: I use an opinionated way basically the entire process is by means of creating a kind cluster as bootstrap, then it creates the master and workers nodes on top of EC2 instances.